# Flex appengine mongoDb

Tags: php, mongodb, google-app-engine

Im using flex appengine, but when I deploy I receive this error message:

```
mongodb/mongodb 1.3.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.4.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

Comment: You need to install the mongodb extension, as `"the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system."` is telling you. How you do that depends on your system, but google will probably tell you if you ask "How to install php ext-mongodb on <insert your system>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By Default `mongodb` extension is not enabled in `Flex` you need to
>   enable via composer.

Example:

`composer require ext-mongodb:*`

or

```
{
"require": {
    "ext-mongodb": "*"
  }
}
```

and make sure you added `php.ini` file in root directory with `"extension=mongodb.so"` enabled  and you can add library with `composer require "mongodb/mongodb:^1.0.0"`

More Details: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docker/tree/master/php-onbuild#enabling-extensions